# JQuery syntax explaination required, possibly associated with Selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

When I'm looking into http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring, I cannot understand the syntax.

I actually set up a similar script at JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/huyoumo/HUc2L/24/

Here's the code snippet:

```
 var methods = {
 init : function( options ) {

   return this.each(function(){

     var $this = $(this),
         data = $this.data('tooltip'),
         tooltip = $('<div />', {
           text : $this.attr('title')
         });

     // If the plugin hasn't been initialized yet
     if ( ! data ) {

       /*
         Do more setup stuff here
       */

       $(this).data('tooltip', {
           target : $this,
           tooltip : tooltip
       });

     }
   });
 },
```

to be more specific:

```
  tooltip = $('<div />', {
           text : $this.attr('title')
  });
```

I debugged the code and find out the tooltip is a JQuery object (appearently), which only has one child (a HTMLDivElement).

I tried to google JQuery selector as key word but there's no luck. Could anyone shed the light and explain what it does?

Thanks.

Youmo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the doc for that http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

```
var foo = $('<div>',
  {
           class : "FooBar"
  });
```

Is actually creating a jquery object and sets the props defined between the curly brackets (in this case class). You can return it with foo.attr("class").

In your case the text prop is set, and that is equal to the inner html of the object (returned with .text()).

Also fixed your fiddle (onload was never called because of the capitalized D in document :) http://jsfiddle.net/HUc2L/26/

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm after. Just not too sure what key words I need to search. Thanks for your time and effort to help me get out of the mist :D

Answer (score 0):

Try out this at [jqfundamentals.com/](http://jqfundamentals.com/) they have better explanations

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply. After I look through the link you provided, I can spot the syntax that I'm after. As bang's answer is more precise to my question, I'll set his/hers as answer. Much appreciated your help though.